# how to change route for each tab in uib-tabset

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

When I choose a tab, I want the url to change. should I create a state for each tab ?

This is my code which works fine without changing the state .

**My app.js**

```
var myApp=angular.module('app', ['ui.router','ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);

myApp.config([
            '$stateProvider',
            '$urlRouterProvider',
            function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

                $stateProvider.state('/', {
                    url: "",
                    views: {
                      "ratios": { templateUrl: "views/requetes.html" },
                      "reqBase": {templateUrl: "views/common.html" },
                      "SQLconsole": {templateUrl: "views/console.html" },
                    }

                  });
                $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
            }]);



myApp.controller('TabsCtrl', function ($rootScope, $state, $scope, $window) {

     $scope.tabs = [
                    { title: "ratios", route: "ratios", active: true },
                    { title: "requetes de Base", route: "reqBase", active: false },
                    { title: "Console", route: "SQLconsole", active: false },
                ];

});
```

**Tabset definition:**

```
<div data-ng-controller="TabsCtrl">    

     <uib-tabset>
                <uib-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" disable="tab.disabled">
                    <div ui-view="{{tab.route}}"></div>
                </uib-tab>
            </uib-tabset>

    </div>
```

Comment: There will be one root state where you will show tabs inside the tab-content you will have another ui-view which will load tab content based on state , basically each tab will have its own state.wgich will be child of root state

Comment: The given answers don't use uib-tabset! You say you solved the problem but you don't give your solution. I think I will give a try to https://long2know.com/2016/01/angular-tabbed-navigation/ instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code :

```
var myApp=angular.module('app', ['ui.router','ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
     myApp.config([
          '$stateProvider',
          '$urlRouterProvider',
          function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
               $stateProvider
                    .state('home', {
                         url:"/",
                         templateUrl: "views/requetes.html",
                    })
                    .state('home.ratios', {
                         url:"/ratios",
                         templateUrl: "views/requetes.html",
                    })
                    .state('home.reqBase', {
                         url:"/reqBase",
                         templateUrl: "views/common.html",
                    })
                    .state('home.SQLconsole', {
                         url:"/SQLconsole",
                         templateUrl: "views/console.html"
                    })
                    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
          }]);
```

Here is the working [PLUNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/OlMUUKXN4HL0sOyhAXdp?p=preview) for this code !!

Comment: thank you so much . I used your solution with some modifications and it works :)

Comment: No uib-tabs there... :-(

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned above, I recommend checking out a blog post I made previously regarding this topic.

https://long2know.com/2016/01/angular-tabbed-navigation/

I detail managing state, intercepting state, preventing navigation (conditionally), etc.  It's driven by services and promises that make creating navigation workflow easy and robust.

If you prefer to not follow the link to my blog, here's a plunker:

https://embed.plnkr.co/w5xdJP?autoCloseSidebar&show=preview

And here's the basic config:

```
myApp.config(['$uibModalProvider', '$locationProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($uibModalProvider, $locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $uibModalProvider.options = { animation: true, backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false };
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);

        $urlRouterProvider
            .when('/', '/state1')
            .otherwise("/state1");

        $stateProvider
            .state('tabs', {
                abstract: true,
                url: '/',
                views: {
                    'tabs': {
                        controller: 'tabsCtrl as tc',
                        templateUrl: 'tabs.html',
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('tabs.state1', {
                url: 'state1',
                templateUrl: 'state1.html',
                controller: function () { },
                reloadOnSearch: false
            })
            .state('tabs.state2', {
                url: 'state2',
                templateUrl: 'state2.html',
                controller: function () { },
                reloadOnSearch: false
            })
            .state('tabs.state3', {
                url: 'state3',
                templateUrl: 'state3.html',
                controller: function () { },
                reloadOnSearch: false
            })
            .state('tabs.state4', {
                url: 'state4',
                templateUrl: 'state4.html',
                controller: function () { },
                reloadOnSearch: false
            })
    }]);

myApp.run(['$log', 'navigationService', function ($log, navigationService) {
    // Note, we need a reference to the navigationService so $state events are tracked.
    $log.log("Start.");
}]);
```

However, I usually create a service that contains a list of the states that I will bind to the tabs:

```
var appStates = function ($state) {
    var
        states = [
            { name: 'state1', heading: "Tab 1", route: "tabs.state1", active: false, isVisible: true, href: $state.href("tabs.state1") },
            { name: 'state2', heading: "Tab 2", route: "tabs.state2", active: false, isVisible: true, href: $state.href("tabs.state2") },
            { name: 'state3', heading: "Tab 3", route: "tabs.state3", active: false, isVisible: true, href: $state.href("tabs.state3") },
            { name: 'state4', heading: "Tab 4", route: "tabs.state4", active: false, isVisible: true, href: $state.href("tabs.state4") }
        ];

    return {
        states: states
    };
};

appStates.$inject = ['$state'];
angular.module('long2know.services')
    .factory('appStates', appStates);
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tabs.html">
    <div class="row">
        <uib-tabset>
            <uib-tab ng-repeat="tab in tc.appStates" heading="{{tab.heading}}" active="tab.active" disable="tab.disabled"
                        select="tc.tabSelected(tab.route)">
            </uib-tab>
        </uib-tabset>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-views" data-ui-view></div>
</script>
```

The tabController:

```
   var tabsCtrl = function ($state, $location, $filter, appStates, navigationService) {
        var
            vm = this,            
            initialize = function () {
                vm.appStates = appStates.states;
            };
        vm.tabSelected = function (route) {
            $state.go(route);
        };
        initialize();
    };

    tabsCtrl.$inject = ['$state', '$location', '$filter', 'appStates', 'navigationService'];
    angular
        .module('long2know.controllers')
        .controller('tabsCtrl', tabsCtrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should use nested states for your tabs. Something like below:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('main', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'main.html'
  })
  .state('main.ratios', {
    url: '/ratios',
    templateUrl: 'views/requetes.html'
  })
```

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZDHkFz3fQmXniqrYh7Is) is a similar implementation with a navbar that you can use as an example.