# How can I make the tab in an AngularJS uib-tabset linkable?

Tags: angularjs, hyperlink, angular-ui-bootstrap-tab

I have something like:

```
<uib-tabset active="vm.activeTab">
    <uib-tab index="0" heading="First"> </uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="1" heading="Second"> </uib-tab>
...
<uib-tabset>
```

And my controller recognizes `...#page&tab=second` to navigate here (by looking up the tab name and getting an index to set for the active tab).  How can I expose the URL for each tab so a user can bookmark it or email it to someone or whatever?

I'd be OK with adding an `ng-click` handler.  I tried having that update `location.href` but it refreshes the page.  I've seen answers suggesting `history.pushState()` or `history.replaceState()` but that seems to have the same problem.

I'd be OK with setting the `href` of the tab so the user could pick "Copy link address" from the context menu over the tab but since the tab is an anchor with an empty `href` I'm afraid that would change behavior.  (And I can't figure out how to set that `href`, anyway.)

Maybe I could add "Copy tab address" or something to the context menu.

I reviewed [how to change route for each tab in uib-tabset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944379/how-to-change-route-for-each-tab-in-uib-tabset) but the answer there doesn't reference `uib-tabset` even thought that seems to be what the question is asking about.

Comment: I'm beginning to think this can't be done and may be should be a feature request for Angular.  Thought I'm around 1.5 and it seems unlikely so old a version will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use deep linking to achieve your goal.

This article can help you
[deep link using ui-router](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/04/14/deep-linking-a-tabbed-ui-with-angularjs.aspx).

As we know ui-router is most popular way to manage routing to another state in angular application. Here we create a parent state which hold other children states. Now as you have provided url to them it will act as normal url which can be bookmarked or sent to someone.

```
$stateProvider
  .state("main", { abstract: true, url:"/main", templateUrl:"main.html" })
  .state("main.tab1", { url: "/tab1", templateUrl: "tab1.html" })
  .state("main.tab2", { url: "/tab2", templateUrl: "tab2.html" })
  .state("main.tab3", { url: "/tab3", templateUrl: "tab3.html" });
})
```

Now by adding ng-repeat to generate the tab-list and setting values to select and and active

```
<tabset>
  <tab
    ng-repeat="t in tabs"
        heading="{{t.heading}}"
        select="go(t.route)"
        active="t.active">
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

Controller for this state will go like this

```
$scope.go = function(route){
  $state.go(route);
};

$scope.active = function(route){
  return $state.is(route);
};

$scope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function() {
  $scope.tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
    tab.active = $scope.active(tab.route);
  });
```

This way It can be done